# PCRE regex to Re2 Regex without negative lookahead

Tags: regex, re2

I am trying to use regex to filter emails from certain addresses in my office G Suite account email routing. In order to do so, I have created the following regex in order to do the following:

1. Accept all email address from a domain "domain.com"
2. Reject 2 of all those addresses from that domain.

In order to do so, I created the following regex that will complete the said function:

```
^(?!test|tes2)[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@domain.com$
```

This one will reject both test@domain.com and tes2@domain.com and accept all other combinations from the said domain.

However, G suite does not accept PCRE regex, so I currently cannot achieve this.

Temporarily, I created the following Re2 regex to accept all email addresses from the said domain:

```
(\W|^)[\w.+\-]{0,25}@(domain)\.com(\W|$)
```

How can I expand this to allow the functionality intended since lookarounds are not allowed in re2 regex?

Answer (score 2):

Because this negative lookahead is fixed size, it's relatively straightforward to expand it like so. It does explode in complexity though; I've added comments and spacing for readability.

```
^
( # not /^t/
       [A-SU-Z0-9._%+-][A-Z0-9._%+-]*
| # /^t/ but not /^te/
  t   ([A-DF-Z0-9._%+-][A-Z0-9._%+-]*)?
| # /^te/ but not /^tes/
  te  ([A-RT-Z0-9._%+-][A-Z0-9._%+-]*)?
| # /^tes/ but not /^tes[t2]/
  tes ([A-SU-Z013-9._%+-][A-Z0-9._%+-]*)?
) @domain.com $
```

Comment: Interesting. So, if we are applying this to two completely different ones (since test and tes2 are very similar), say john and dave, should I follow a similar principle?

Comment: @KavindaKeshanRasnayake It will end up with two separate branches at each character position, e.g. `(?!abc|def)` → `[^ad] | a[^b] | ab[^c] | d[^e] | de[^f]`

Answer (score 0):

Very quick and dirty tool (PHP) only to exclude a-z at the beginning of a string.

Nod to ephemient answer above.

```
// Get The Alphabet
$alphas = range('a', 'z');
// Set the string we want to exclude
$string = str_split("server");

print "^(";
$i = 0;
$pre = "";
foreach ($string as $letter) {

    if ($i > 0) {
        print "|";
    }
    $key = array_search($letter, $alphas);
    switch ((int)$key) {

        case 0:
            print $pre."[b-z0-9._%+-]*";
            break;

        case 25:
            print $pre."[a-y0-9._%+-]*";
            break;

        default:
            print $pre."[a-".$alphas[((int)$key-1)]."0-9._%+-][".$alphas[((int)$key+1)]."-z0-9._%+-]*";
            break;
    }

    $pre .= $letter;
    $i++;
}

print ")(.*)$";
```

Output:

```
^([a-r0-9._%+-][t-z0-9._%+-]*|s[a-d0-9._%+-][f-z0-9._%+-]*|se[a-q0-9._%+-][s-z0-9._%+-]*|ser[a-u0-9._%+-][w-z0-9._%+-]*|serv[a-d0-9._%+-][f-z0-9._%+-]*|serve[a-q0-9._%+-][s-z0-9._%+-]*)(.*)$
```